# How to declare a module to do named imports?

Tags: typescript, module, graphql, graphql-tag

I'm using [graphql-tag](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag). My files are like that.

./operation.graphql

```
Query User {
   ...
}
```

./test.ts

```
import { User } from './operation.graphql'; /// Module ''*.graphql'' has no exported member 'User'.
```

./index.d.ts

```
declare module '*.graphql' {
    import { DocumentNode } from 'graphql';

    const value:DocumentNode;

    export default value;
}
```

A application is work well, but I want to prevent that error.

When I do default import is work well, but as you see, I got an error at named imports.

How to declare this? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the name of the export you want is different for each GraphQL file, TypeScript won't parse your GraphQL file to figure it out automatically.  Either you need a separate module declaration for each GraphQL file (and you'll need to set your `baseUrl` and `paths` so you can use non-relative imports, or it might work to put a `d.ts` file alongside each GraphQL file instead of using `declare module`, I'm not sure):

```
declare module 'operation.graphql' {
    import { DocumentNode } from 'graphql';

    export const User: DocumentNode;
}
```

Or you can give up and let all the GraphQL files be of type `any`:

```
declare module '*.graphql';
```

Comment: Thanks. :) it's helpful!

Comment: I ran into this today, and ended up using [@graphql-codegen/typescript-graphql-files-modules](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/typescript/typescript-graphql-files-modules) to generate the types, with named exports, from the gql docs.